# Exporting NN parameters in lax.scan

Tags: neural-network, jax, dqn

I am training a DQN agent using JAX. The DQN framework is based on `lax.scan` for iterating over episodes. In order to assess the performance of the agent after training, I would like to store the parameters (weights & biases) of the neural network per episode. However, it appears that my computer's memory is not sufficient when I use larger networks (4 hidden layers with 256, 128, 64, 32 nodes).

When I try to simply store the parameters in the output dictionary of `lax.scan`, I get the following error:
`jaxlib.xla_extension.XlaRuntimeError: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Out of memory allocating 655360000000 bytes.`

Any ideas on how to bypass this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than attempting to return the array of intermediate parameters, you could log them at runtime using [`jax.experimental.io_callback`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.experimental.io_callback.html) or [`jax.debug.callback`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.debug.callback.html).

This would likely incur some performance penalties, but if you add it for testing/debugging purposes only, that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Actually, I would like to avoid a performance penalty. I would like to store the NN parameters every few episodes of training, so that I can idenify the optimal agent after training. Is there any way to export the parameters in a file without a serious compromise in speed?

Comment: It really depends on the problem: if your nn training iterations are much slower than the cost of passing data to the host to log it, then the performance impact will be relatively small. If the iterations are faster than the cost of calling back to the host, then the relative performance impact will be larger.